# Yocto bitbake ERROR: quilt-native-0.66-r0 do_configure

Tags: yocto, fpga, xilinx, bitbake, vivado

My FPGA based design is based on Vivado 2020.2 and Yocto running on Ubuntu 2020.04.6 LTS. I have FPGA design A that builds successfully .bit and .xsa files successfully without any critical warnings and errors. Yocto builds successfully to create binary images.

However, when design A is upgraded to design B with a licensed IP in it, then, .bit and .xsa files have been successfully generated with a critical warning and no errors.

> [Vivado 12-1790] Evaluation License Warning: This design contains one or more IP cores that use separately licensed features. If the design has been configured to make use of evaluation features, please note that these features will cease to function after a certain period of time. Please consult the core datasheet to determine whether the core which you have configured will be affected. Evaluation features should NOT be used in production systems.
>
> Evaluation cores found in this design:
> IP core 'xxv_ethernet_0' (xxv_ethernet_v3_3_0) was generated with multiple features:
> IP feature 'x_eth_mac@2020.11' was enabled using a design_linking license.
> IP feature 'xxv_eth_basekr@2020.11' was enabled using a design_linking license.
> IP feature 'xxv_eth_mac_pcs@2020.11' was enabled using a design_linking license.
> IP feature 'xxv_tsn_802d1cm@2020.11' was enabled using a design_linking license.
>
> Resolution: If a new IP Core license was added, in order for the new license to be picked up, the current netlist needs to be updated by resetting and re-generating the IP output products before bitstream generation.

As the hardware delta change includes a time-limited licensed IP, this critical warning can be ignored as long as the hardware can be operated with no issues within the time-limit.

But, the actual problem is that Yocto build fails with the following error.

> ERROR: quilt-native-0.66-r0 do_configure: Execution of '/yocto/sat/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/quilt-native/0.66-r0/temp/run.do_configure.2604' failed with exit code 126:
> /home/user/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv: line 138: /home/user/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv-exec: Argument list too long
> WARNING: exit code 126 from a shell command.
>
> ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /yocto/sat/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/quilt-native/0.66-r0/temp/log.do_configure.2604
>
> ERROR: Task
> (/yocto/sat/sources/core/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.66.bb:do_configure)
> failed with exit code '1'

It seems to be pyenv error, however, I cannot run bitbake by disabling/uninstalling pyenv (as recommended in another posts), which end with another bitbake error mentioning pyenv package missing.

Expected result is creating of yocto images, as .bit and .xsa files are generated successfully in Vivado and no changes in yocto build routines are introduced.

Comment: So what's inside the quilt recipe and `run.do_configure.2604` file?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and found a solution that works for me. I have not explored the problem down to the root, and I also cannot explain the hardware (.xsa) dependency in this stackoverflow question, but I hope my answer can still be helpful.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.6 in a WSL2 environment. I exported a successfully created .xsa from Vivado 2020.2 and tried to build the kernel from there. I use an older version of Yocto (Zeus) and bitbake. According to https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2019-October/047111.html, that requires Python 3.7.3 and 3.7.4 whilst I had python 3.8 installed. Therefore, I installed python 3.7.3 and 3.7.4 using pyenv, and set python 3.7.4 as global pyenv version:

```
pyenv install 3.7.4
pyenv install 3.7.3
pyenv global 3.7.4
```

Then after making sure the used python version is 3.7.4 (`python --version`) and the bitbake build was cleaned, I could succesfully build the kernel. Notice that I still have 2 warnings left:

```
WARNING: Host distribution "ubuntu-20.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
WARNING: Your host glibc verson (2.31) is newer than that in uninative (2.30). Disabling uninative so that sstate is not corrupted.
```

The warnings are off course there because an older Yocto release is used.